# Getting a blank project in my ionic view app in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, view

I just followed all the instructions on the ionic pro framework i build it but in the ionic view application it is giving me a blank project but in testing my app it is not a blank app please i need a help on this!!

Comment: Could you give us some details please? Which command did you ran? `ionic serve - l`, `ionic cordova run`? Do you have logs in the console? Could you give us the result of `ionic info `?

Comment: No noo i ran the ionic serve and it worked well i have finished my project but i am using the ionic view to test my app on a real device their it is giving me a blank project